# Copying a file and adding it to startup

Tags: c#, copy, startup

I'm creating an application where I'm copying the file to the user's appdata and then adding a registry key so that the file runs at startup.
I get a URI exception while running it.
Here's the fragment of the code that's giving me trouble..

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\My_Application");
if (rk != null)
{
    //Do nothing as the program is already added to startup
}
else
{
    string newpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\My_Application\\" + "My_Application.exe";
    File.Copy(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.ToString(), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\My_Application\\" + "My_Application.exe");
    RegistryKey startup = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    startup.SetValue("My_Application", "\"" + newpath);
}
```

Comment: just a hint, you can use `Path.Combine` to merge directories, and/or the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` for the \ character (`Combine` wouldn't require it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `startup.SetValue()`.  You are escaping a `"` character and I think you want to escape a `\`:

```
startup.SetValue("My_Application", "\\" + newpath);
```

If you actually mean to escape a `"` then you probably need one on both sides:

```
startup.Setvalue("My_Application", "\"" + newpath + "\"");
```

Or Typically this should work (I'm not super familiar with this API)

```
startup.SetValue("My_Application", newpath);
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I've tried all of your solutions.

Comment: Can you post the exact error and which line os throwing the exception please?

Answer (score 1):

Use System.IO.Path.Combine for path concatenation. Also, make sure that the destination directory exists before copying.

```
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appData, "My_Application", "My_Application.exe");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(newpath));
File.Copy(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.ToString(), newpath);
RegistryKey startup = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
startup.SetValue("My_Application", newpath);
```

Comment: That would do it. I assumed File.Copy created the directory for me.